# Cannot Find either column or aggregate, or name is ambiguous

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to import a XML table to a SQL table. I created a basic table in the SQL Server database but I'm getting an error:

> Cannot find either column "var1" or the user-defined function or aggregate "var1.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Code:

```
declare @xmldata as xml

set @xmldata = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn)AS Bulkcolumn
                FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '<filename>.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as X)

INSERT INTO table1(var1, var2, var3)
    SELECT
        var1 = var1.value('var1', 'int'),
        var2 = var2.value('var2', 'int'),
        var3 = var3.value('var3', 'int')
```

I must've gone wrong somewhere, specifically when I attempt to import it into the SQL Server table.

Comment: What is this part doing? `var1.value('var1', 'int')` - You are calling it like a function.

Comment: The insert into part I'm not entirely sure, but my objective is to get the XML file into a sql table. I've looked around on this site and this is my understanding of how to do it. From my logic the var part inserts values to the sql table maybe?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I think the third query is what you want.

Comment: Hi Donald. You are reading your XML from file into your variable `@xmldata`. If you try a `SELECT @xmldata;` you will see the result (click on it). Please poste this result in order to help you. At the moment you are reading your XML, but you are not doing anything with this afterwards...

Comment: Hey Shnugo, unfortunately I can't show you much details due to the file being filled with personal information but by using a select statement, I few the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what var1.value is supposed to do and even the compiler is confused.

Other than that your Insert is ok, just change what I have for value1, value2, and value3 to the values you want in those columns. If data type of var1, var2, or var3 is number then you can remove the single quotes. Any other data type should need to be wrapped in single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO table1(var1, var2, var3)
    SELECT
        var1 = 'value1',
        var2 = 'value2',
        var3 = 'value3'
```

I normally write an insert this way though.

```
INSERT INTO table1(var1, var2, var3)
    SELECT
        'value1' AS 'var1',
        'value2' AS 'var2',
        'value3' AS 'var3'
```

---

If you want that xml data in a column of a table then try this. You will need a table named `table1` with at least a column named `XMLString` as datatype `nvarchar(max)`

```
INSERT INTO table1(XMLString)
        SELECT
            @xmldata AS 'XMLString'
```

Comment: I want to insert the whole column that has many records. How can I do this?

Comment: Is you XML data coming from multiple files? If so, can you merge into one file?

Comment: it's coming from 1 file, but I'm getting a compilation error saying that var1 is an invalid column name.

Comment: Is var1, var2, and var3 column names in your table? What is you intention for the three columns? Is the xml data going into only var1 column?

Comment: var1, var 2, and var 3 are my column names and I want to put the values correcsponding to each of var1,2,and 3 into each respective column

Comment: Ok you want to put var1, var2, and var3 into a table and you confirmed you have a table with those column names. Where are you getting the values for var1, var2, var3 to send to that table? I assume it's the OPENROWSET, but that isn't creating three columns.

Comment: oh, maybe that's why. I have the 3 columns in an XML file which I got by excecuting the SELECT FROM XML AUTO export function.

Comment: Glad you might have figured it out. Post your working solution as an answer and explain what you did wrong.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet. The OPENROWSET only opens one column? How can I do this to create 3?

Comment: It sounds like you need to open the xml file and query it to get the columns you want. Try using OPENXML('file') as a table in a select query. From here you should be able to select the three columns you need and insert into your table. I would start out with a Select * From OPENXML('file') to see what I'm dealing with.